# A data connection is required to connect to Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client, google-drive-android-api

I used GoogleApiClient in my Activity to upload files to drive. Instantiated GoogleApiClient,and connect on onCreate of Activity,then disconnect on onDestroy f Activity.When I starts activity shows a dialog as "Network Error: A data connection is required to connect to Google Play Services".

1. Is Internet connectivity must to connect GoogleApiClient?
2. So Internet is must every time I launch my Activity?
3. I read Google Drive API works,so if Internet disconnected,Google Drive API will work or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should have an active internet connection.

Comment: I try to connect GoogleApiClient.An error Calling connect() while still connected, missing disconnect().But I connected in onCreated and disconnected in onDestroy. Why it happens? Then once I connected GoogleApiClient with internet,then goes to offline,my drive api will work or not?

Comment: Already available <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: GoogleApiClient expects Internet connection for first time only.After WIFI connection off,GoogleApiClient connects even after disconnected and again connected.

Comment: i just try quickstart sample i have some error please see this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636659/upload-file-to-google-drive-using-google-play-serivces-libwithout-supporting-ja please help me